# Remove duplicated row in mysql

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have a mysql table like this:

```
   id   employee_number  name
    1        1             A
    2        2             B
    3        3             C
    4        3             C
    5        4             D
    6        5             E
    7        5             E            
    8        6             F
    9        7             G
    8        8             H
    9        9             I
   10      ....    
   11      ....
   12      ....
        many duplicated 
        employee_number
```

I want to remove 1 row of employee_number 3 and 5(id 3 or 4 and 6 or 7 don't matter). 
I can see the duplicated rows with the following sql but not sure what to do next. I apprciate if someone can help me out on this one. Thanks a lot!

```
SELECT COUNT( id ) , employee_number
FROM  `employees` 
GROUP BY employee_number
```

**Updated:**

**CREATE TABLE new_table as
SELECT * FROM old_table WHERE 1 GROUP BY employee_number;**

Well. I found this statements and it works. Thanks guys.

Comment: Before you can remove anything you need to decide the criteria for the row to keep, remembering that you will be throwing away some data.

Comment: I already found the solution. see update.

Comment: Your Are upvoting everyone without even checking if answers work, I guess i should post more answer on your posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `employees`
WHERE ID 
NOT IN 
(SELECT MAX(B.ID) FROM 
                  (SELECT employee_number
                   FROM `employees`
                   GROUP BY employee_number
                   HAVING COUNT(*)>1) A,
                   `employees` B
 WHERE A.employee_number=B.employee_number
 GROUP BY B.employee_number
);
```

Answer (score 1):

U could use SQL like this(in oracle):
Query duplicated rows 
SELECT * FROM employees t1 where t1.rowid> (SELECT min(t2.rowid) FROM employees t2 where t2.name=t1.name) ;

delete fromv employees t1 where t1.rowid>(select min(t2.rowid) from employees t2 where t2.no=t1.no);

Answer (score 0):

You can self join the tables.

Say not to delete the same record. ie, (NOT Employee.id=vtable.id)

if not same record and if employee_number matches, then delete.

```
delete from Employee
USING Employee, Employeeas vtable
WHERE (NOT Employee.id=vtable.id)
AND (Employee.employee_number=vtable.employee_number)
```